# I am getting this error : XML Parsing Error: junk after document element

Tags: php, xml, xml-parsing

I am trying to implement a store locator using php, javascript, html, css. The first step is to get my database query parsing in xml format, But I am getting an error that does not make sense to me.
it says :

> { XML Parsing Error: junk after document element Line Number 3, Column
>   9:        
>   --------^}

The weird part is when I hit enter in line 3 to push error to line 4, error context does not change, it seems that error does not have any thing with the the code.

The XML:

```
<parks storeName="Devonshire Park" streetNumber="1250" lat="49.245020" lng="-123.13364" distance="0.3444475521254494"></parks>
<parks storeName="Shaughnessy Park" streetNumber="1300" lat="49.255715" lng="-123.13506" distance="0.4027917748443472"></parks>
<parks storeName="Braemar Park" streetNumber="895" lat="49.247615" lng="-123.12363" distance="0.46626204419188244"></parks>
<parks storeName="Douglas Park" streetNumber="801" lat="49.252493" lng="-123.12222" distance="0.5285969452661102"></parks>
<parks storeName="Angus Park" streetNumber="3600" lat="49.253932" lng="-123.14381" distance="0.5463666448497029"></parks>
<parks storeName="Heather Park" streetNumber="702" lat="49.254765" lng="-123.12110" distance="0.6412282952671712"></parks>
<parks storeName="Granville Park" streetNumber="3001" lat="49.258105" lng="-123.14239" distance="0.6940531309415132"></parks>
<parks storeName="VanDusen Botanical Gardens" streetNumber="5251" lat="49.239181" lng="-123.13129" distance="0.7530451429246237"></parks>
<parks storeName="Quilchena Park" streetNumber="4590" lat="49.243690" lng="-123.14886" distance="0.8262659935827044"></parks>
<parks storeName="Oak Meadows Park" streetNumber="899" lat="49.238445" lng="-123.12579" distance="0.867320490203991"></parks>
<parks storeName="Arbutus Village Park" streetNumber="4202" lat="49.249783" lng="-123.15525" distance="0.9901511999872843"></parks>
<parks storeName="Choklit Park" streetNumber="" lat="49.265482" lng="-123.12890" distance="1.0880158966243803"></parks>
<parks storeName="Prince Edward Park" streetNumber="3773" lat="49.244397" lng="-123.15642" distance="1.1124111373800636"></parks>
<parks storeName="Prince of Wales Park" streetNumber="4780" lat="49.244397" lng="-123.15642" distance="1.1124111373800636"></parks>
<parks storeName="Queen Elizabeth Park" streetNumber="4600" lat="49.240978" lng="-123.11202" distance="1.1445698543044514"></parks>
<parks storeName="Willow Park" streetNumber="802" lat="49.264868" lng="-123.12203" distance="1.14618861456822"></parks>
<parks storeName="Hillcrest Park" streetNumber="4501" lat="49.244734" lng="-123.10841" distance="1.1801942385262174"></parks>
<parks storeName="Ravine Park" streetNumber="2159" lat="49.240902" lng="-123.15593" distance="1.1988469137694855"></parks>
<parks storeName="Granville Loop Park" streetNumber="1435" lat="49.267284" lng="-123.13754" distance="1.2094922772420964"></parks>
<parks storeName="Charleson Park" streetNumber="999" lat="49.266995" lng="-123.12420" distance="1.2439538809012058"></parks>
```

Comment: Can you add the xml file's content to the question?

Comment: Please include the XML file in question, or at least a snippet in and around Line 3, Column 9. It could be many things, one possibly that quickly came to mind was that perhaps it could be something you're using that is converting whitespace/returns/nulls for typesafe insertion into a database. So without the XML, and some code context, I don't know if we can help much.

Comment: @user1836957: I saw you had problems formatting the XML (indent with four spaces and it's preformatted code). I edited your question now to show it, hope this helps. Looks like Luke Wyatt is right with his answer.

Answer (score 12):

That is not really XML if there is no single root element. 
Try wrapping all of those  elements in a single root. 
The "junk" the parser is complaining about is the multiple  roots after the first one,
which is the only one it considers valid.

Answer (score 9):

The problem here is with the XML content.  The error is stating that there are characters outside of an XML element.  Such as

```
<document>
  <element>
  </element>
</document>
<junk></junk>  <-- after the root element
```

Post the XML being parsed if you'd like further help.

Answer (score 0):

There is likely content after the XML body that the browser doesn't expect. Make sure the browser is ONLY receiving the XML and nothing else, including whitespace or line breaks.

Answer (score -1):

Well try to use eiter CDATA to wrap your content from database as there might be junk inside  the text.
An other solution is to make a function which will replace characters that can't be parsed

Comment: I had this issue on my site 
The issue was that I had defined two </urlset>